# Linq query in a Complex Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have Dictionary like

```
Dictionary<int?, CompositeAccount> dicAccount = new Dictionary<int?, CompositeAccount>();
```

In `CompositeAccount` type there is a list of individuals:

```
List<Individuals> individuals
```

And in Individuals type there is an attribute `Name`.

Now I want to use Linq in `dicAccount` and get individuals type data in which the name is `Divyam`.

Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: *Can anyone help me to solve my problem?* For now: only you, by providing an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating your problem.

Comment: Is my problem  not understandable ??

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your **problem** is understandable, but you are expected to show some effort - what have you tried, where are you stuck. Your question is pretty basic, if you want to use LINQ, you need to know at least the basic stuff. `from ... from ... where ... select ..` - as you can see, nothing unusual.

Comment: What @GertArnold is referring to is that if you provide complete though minimal code example with your question then you spare the people trying to help you from making assupmtions and re-create missing parts of your code. Then they can spend more time helping you and providing an example that solves your problem. This will provide you with better help and also enhance this questions value as an example for other people seeking solutions to similar problems.
What would be most immediately helpful in this case would be to also provide the code for `CompositeAccount` and `Individual` classes

Answer (score 1):

So you want to select Individuals with *Name = Divyam*. Then, using Linq:

```
List<Individuals> results =
    dicAccount.Values.Where(x => x.Individuals != null)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Individuals)
                .Where(indv => indv != null && indv.Name == "Divyam").ToList();
```

Using `dicAccount.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Individuals)` you a list of all Individuals in the entire dictionary.

Then you use `Where` to find a record with a specified condition (Which is *Name == "Divyam"* here).

Then you use `Select` to retrieve the entire `Individuals` object.

**To get a single individual (First occurrence):**

```
  Individuals divyam =
    dicAccount.Values.Where(x => x.Individuals != null)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Individuals)
                .FirstOrDefault(indv => indv != null && indv.Name == "Divyam");
```

Note that `divyam` is null if no record found with that Name. If you want to throw an exception if none is found, use `.First();` instead of `FirstOrDefault();` If you need throw an exception if you have more than one record with that name, then you need to use `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: Thanks for giving me right solution. Hey If I want to get only single Individual ,i mean not the list just single Individual record. Then what will be the LINQ query???

Comment: @DivyamSrivastava What if there are multiple individuals with `Name = Divyam`. You want the first one ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse....Actually in my case there are only single record occur with this particular name.

Comment: @DivyamSrivastava check the edited answer.

Comment: What you want here is `SingleOrDefault()` if you know that the names are unique.
If you don't know that the names are unique and use `FirstOrDefault()` then most likely you have a problem - either you have pure duplicates
(most likely a bug) or you have several records with the same name and then just returning a semi randomly chosen instance (the one that happens to come first) would is likely not what is expected by the user/client of your code.

Comment: @DivyamSrivastava did that work fine for you ?

Comment: Hey thanks .....I faced a new problem, In the List of Individuals, some list are blank so this gives an error is that object reference is not set to an instance of object. So can the LINQ query shold be improved or some thing else???

Comment: I mean, Can we filter these null Individuals List in LINQ query?

Comment: @DivyamSrivastava yes, check the update.

Comment: @DivyamSrivastava please mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = dicAccount
    .SelectMany(kv => kv.Value.individuals)
    .Where(i => i.Name.Equals("Divyam"))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the Lambda syntax

```
Individuals result = dicAccount.Values.SelectMany(c => c.individuals).SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "Divyam");
```

Comment: Also, I am a bit curious as to why you use an `int?` instead of an `int` as a dictionary key there may of course be a valid reason but it is highly unusual as it will only hold max one value with null key and even then you will not find it again (when querying the dictionary by id) if it gets assigned a proper key (id?)